# Multiple fields single model update in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a form with multiple fields in knockoutjs. I am creating model data with json. 
I have created a HTML Form with multiple fileds for searching in this data via knockouts.

The problem i am getting is the searching/filtration going on "OR" condition basis. When select other filter previous one gone and searching goes on current fields only.How can i overcome with this problem.

Knockout JS

```
var outfitterJSON = <?php echo $this->JSON; ?>

var ViewModel = function(outfittersJSON) {
    var self = this;

    // Inputs
    self.nameSearch = ko.observable();
    self.registrationNumber = ko.observable();
    self.unitNumber = ko.observable();


    // Checkboxes & Radios
    self.activeFilters = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.regionFilters = ko.observableArray([]);

    // Items
    self.outfitters = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.outfitters_temp = ko.observableArray([]);

    //populate outfitters object and add visible flag for knockout to show/hide                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    outfittersJSON.forEach(function(value) {
        value.visible = ko.observable(true);
        self.outfitters().push(value);
    });

    // Search by Checkbox filters
    self.activeFilters.subscribe(function(filters) {
      //  console.log(filters);                    
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.outfitters(), function(outfitter) {
            if (filters.length) {
                var shouldShowOutfitter = true;
                //hide based on fitler array
                filters.forEach(function(filter){
                    if (outfitter[filter] !== 'yes')
                        shouldShowOutfitter = false;
                });
                outfitter.visible(shouldShowOutfitter);
            } else {
                //show all if none are selected
                outfitter.visible(true);
            }
        });
    });

    // Search by Business Name
    self.nameSearch.subscribe(function(query) {
        //console.log(query);
       //console.log(self.outfitters())

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.outfitters(), function(outfitter) {

            if(outfitter['businessname'].toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {

                outfitter.visible(true);
            } else {
                outfitter.visible(false);
            }
        });
    });

    // Search by Registration Number
    self.registrationNumber.subscribe(function(regNum) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.outfitters(), function(outfitter) {
            if(outfitter['reg'].indexOf(regNum) >= 0) {
                outfitter.visible(true);
            } else {
                outfitter.visible(false);
            }
        });
    });

    // Search by Hunt Units
    self.unitNumber.subscribe(function(unitNum) {                    
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.outfitters(), function(outfitter) {
            if (outfitter['unit'].indexOf(unitNum.toString()) >= 0) {
                outfitter.visible(true);
            } else {
                //show all if none are selected
                outfitter.visible(false);
            }
        });
    });

    // Search by Region Numbers
    self.regionFilters.subscribe(function(region) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.outfitters(), function(outfitter) {
            if(outfitter['region'] === region) {
                outfitter.visible(true);
            } else if (region === 'any') {
                outfitter.visible(true);
            } else {
                outfitter.visible(false);
            }

        });
    });

};

var vm = new ViewModel(outfitterJSON);
ko.applyBindings(vm);

var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

// Reset all filters visually and fire click/change events
// so KO.js knows that items have been changed and can update accordingly
$('#outfitter-filter').on('reset', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('input, select, textarea').each(function () {
        if ($(this).is('input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"]')) {
            if ($(this).is(':checked') !== $(this)[0].defaultChecked) {
                $(this).val($(this)[0].defaultChecked);
                $(this).trigger('click');
                $(this).trigger('change');
            }
        } else {
            if ($(this).val() !== $(this)[0].defaultValue) {
                $(this).val($(this)[0].defaultValue);
                $(this).change();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

HTML Form

```
<form action="" id="outfitter-filter" class="search_form">
<p><input type="reset" class="reset btn btn-sm btn-primary">

<strong>Filters:</strong> <span data-bind="text: nameSearch"></span> <span data-bind="text: activeFilters"></span>

</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <!-- Name Search -->
        <label for="">Business Name</label>
        <input type="search" data-bind="value: nameSearch, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search by Name"/>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <!-- Registration Number -->
        <label for="">Registration #</label>
        <input type="search" data-bind="value: registrationNumber, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Registration Number"/>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <!-- Unit # -->
        <label for="">Hunt Unit #</label>
        <input type="search" data-bind="value: unitNumber, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" id="hunt-unit" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Hunt Unit #"/>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <!-- Regions -->
        <label for="">Regions</label> <br>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="NW" value="NW" data-bind="checked: regionFilters"> NW
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="SW" value="SW" data-bind="checked: regionFilters"> SW
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="NE" value="NE" data-bind="checked: regionFilters"> NE
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="SE" value="SE" data-bind="checked: regionFilters"> SE
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="any" value="any" data-bind="checked: regionFilters"> Any Region
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <!-- Big Game Interests -->
        <fieldset id="big-game">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <strong>Big Game of Interest:</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="muledeer" type="checkbox" name="muledeer" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Mule Deer</label></div>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="whitetaildeer" type="checkbox" name="whitetaildeer" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Whitetail Deer</label></div>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="antelope" type="checkbox" name="antelope" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Antelope</label></div>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="elk" type="checkbox" name="elk" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Elk</label></div>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="mountainlion" type="checkbox" name="mountainlion" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Mountain Lion</label></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="mountaingoat" type="checkbox" name="mountaingoat" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Mountain Goat</label></div>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="bear" type="checkbox" name="bear" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Bear</label></div>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="bighornsheep" type="checkbox" name="bighornsheep" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Bighorn Sheep</label></div>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="moose" type="checkbox" name="moose" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Moose</label></div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <!-- Small Game -->
        <fieldset id="small-game">
            <p><strong>Small Game of Interest:</strong></p>
            <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="smallgame" type="checkbox" name="smallgame" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">General Small Game</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="turkey" type="checkbox" name="turkey" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Turkey</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="uplandbirds" type="checkbox" name="uplandbirds" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Upland Birds</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="waterfowl" type="checkbox" name="waterfowl" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Waterfowl</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="varmints" type="checkbox" name="varmints" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Varmints</label></div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <!-- Lodging -->
        <fieldset id="lodging">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <strong>Lodging:</strong>
            </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="lodge" type="checkbox" name="lodge" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Lodge</label></div>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="cabins" type="checkbox" name="cabins" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Cabins</label></div>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="trailers" type="checkbox" name="trailers" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Trailers</label></div>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="tents" type="checkbox" name="tents" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Tents</label></div>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="motel" type="checkbox" name="motel" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Motel</label></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="wildernesscamps" type="checkbox" name="wildernesscamps" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Wilderness Camps</label></div>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="handicapaccessible" type="checkbox" name="handicapaccessible" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Handicap Accessible</label></div>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="camping" type="checkbox" name="camping" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Camping</label></div>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="dropcamps" type="checkbox" name="dropcamps" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Drop Camps</label></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>         
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <!-- Summer Recreation -->
        <fieldset id="summer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <strong>Summer Recreation:</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="flyfishing" type="checkbox" name="flyfishing" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Fly Fishing</label></div>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="spincasting" type="checkbox" name="spincasting" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Spin Casting</label></div>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="lakefishing" type="checkbox" name="lakefishing" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Lake Fishing</label></div>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="streamfishing" type="checkbox" name="streamfishing" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Stream Fishing</label></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="floattrips" type="checkbox" name="floattrips" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Float Trips</label></div>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="rafting" type="checkbox" name="rafting" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Rafting</label></div>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="other" type="checkbox" name="other" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Other</label></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <!-- Special Services -->
        <fieldset id="services">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <strong>Special Services:</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="packtrips" type="checkbox" name="packtrips" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Pack Trips</label></div>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="horserides" type="checkbox" name="horserides" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Horse Rides</label></div>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="cattledrives" type="checkbox" name="cattledrives" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Cattle Drives</label></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="horserental" type="checkbox" name="horserental" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Horse Rental</label></div>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="guideschools" type="checkbox" name="guideschools" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Guide Schools</label></div>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="overnighttrips" type="checkbox" name="overnighttrips" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Overnight Trips</label></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <!-- Winter -->
        <fieldset id="winter">
            <p><strong>Winter:</strong></p>
            <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="sleighrides" type="checkbox" name="sleighrides" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Sleigh Rides</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="snowmobiletours" type="checkbox" name="snowmobiletours" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">SnowMobile Tours/Rental</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="skiing" type="checkbox" name="skiing" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Skiing</label></div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <!-- Operating Area -->
        <fieldset id="operating-area">
            <p><strong>Operating Area</strong></p>
            <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="blm" type="checkbox" name="blm" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">BLM</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="nationalforest" type="checkbox" name="nationalforest" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">National Forest</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="privateland" type="checkbox" name="privateland" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Private Land</label></div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <!-- Other -->
        <fieldset id="other">
            <p><strong>Other</strong></p>
            <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="ranchingforwildlife" type="checkbox" name="ranchingforwildlife" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Ranching for Wildlife</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox"><label><input value="workingcattleranch" type="checkbox" name="workingcattleranch" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Working Cattle Ranch</label></div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you clarify your question and provide a JSFiddle that simulates your problem? I don't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

I've copied your code to the snippet below, and it runs as I expect (output on the console indicates whether items would be shown).

```js
var ViewModel = function(outfittersJSON) {
    var self = this;

    // Inputs
    self.nameSearch = ko.observable();
    self.registrationNumber = ko.observable();
    self.unitNumber = ko.observable();


    // Checkboxes & Radios
    self.activeFilters = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.regionFilters = ko.observableArray([]);

    // Items
    self.outfitters = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.outfitters_temp = ko.observableArray([]);

    //populate outfitters object and add visible flag for knockout to show/hide
    outfittersJSON.forEach(function(value) {
        value.visible = ko.observable(true);
        self.outfitters().push(value);
    });

    // Search by Checkbox filters
    self.activeFilters.subscribe(function(filters) {
        console.debug(filters);                    
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.outfitters(), function(outfitter) {
            if (filters.length) {
                var shouldShowOutfitter = true;
                //hide based on fitler array
                console.debug("Checking", outfitter, "for", filters);
                filters.forEach(function(filter){
                    if (outfitter[filter] !== 'yes')
                        shouldShowOutfitter = false;
                });
                outfitter.visible(shouldShowOutfitter);
                console.debug("Show?", shouldShowOutfitter);
            } else {
                //show all if none are selected
                outfitter.visible(true);
            }
        });
    });

    // Search by Business Name
    self.nameSearch.subscribe(function(query) {
        //console.log(query);
       //console.log(self.outfitters())

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.outfitters(), function(outfitter) {

            if(outfitter['businessname'].toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {

                outfitter.visible(true);
            } else {
                outfitter.visible(false);
            }
        });
    });

    // Search by Registration Number
    self.registrationNumber.subscribe(function(regNum) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.outfitters(), function(outfitter) {
            if(outfitter['reg'].indexOf(regNum) >= 0) {
                outfitter.visible(true);
            } else {
                outfitter.visible(false);
            }
        });
    });

    // Search by Hunt Units
    self.unitNumber.subscribe(function(unitNum) {                    
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.outfitters(), function(outfitter) {
            if (outfitter['unit'].indexOf(unitNum.toString()) >= 0) {
                outfitter.visible(true);
            } else {
                //show all if none are selected
                outfitter.visible(false);
            }
        });
    });

    // Search by Region Numbers
    self.regionFilters.subscribe(function(region) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.outfitters(), function(outfitter) {
            if(outfitter['region'] === region) {
                outfitter.visible(true);
            } else if (region === 'any') {
                outfitter.visible(true);
            } else {
                outfitter.visible(false);
            }

        });
    });

};

var vm = new ViewModel([{'muledeer':'yes'},{'muledeer':'yes', 'whitetaildeer':'yes'}]);
ko.applyBindings(vm);

var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

// Reset all filters visually and fire click/change events
// so KO.js knows that items have been changed and can update accordingly
$('#outfitter-filter').on('reset', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('input, select, textarea').each(function () {
        if ($(this).is('input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"]')) {
            if ($(this).is(':checked') !== $(this)[0].defaultChecked) {
                $(this).val($(this)[0].defaultChecked);
                $(this).trigger('click');
                $(this).trigger('change');
            }
        } else {
            if ($(this).val() !== $(this)[0].defaultValue) {
                $(this).val($(this)[0].defaultValue);
                $(this).change();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="outfitter-filter" class="search_form">
  <p>
    <input type="reset" class="reset btn btn-sm btn-primary">

    <strong>Filters:</strong>  <span data-bind="text: nameSearch"></span>  <span data-bind="text: activeFilters"></span>

  </p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <!-- Name Search -->
      <label for="">Business Name</label>
      <input type="search" data-bind="value: nameSearch, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search by Name" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <!-- Registration Number -->
      <label for="">Registration #</label>
      <input type="search" data-bind="value: registrationNumber, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Registration Number" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <!-- Unit # -->
      <label for="">Hunt Unit #</label>
      <input type="search" data-bind="value: unitNumber, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" id="hunt-unit" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Hunt Unit #" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <!-- Regions -->
      <label for="">Regions</label>
      <br>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="NW" value="NW" data-bind="checked: regionFilters">NW
      </label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="SW" value="SW" data-bind="checked: regionFilters">SW
      </label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="NE" value="NE" data-bind="checked: regionFilters">NE
      </label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="SE" value="SE" data-bind="checked: regionFilters">SE
      </label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="any" value="any" data-bind="checked: regionFilters">Any Region
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <!-- Big Game Interests -->
      <fieldset id="big-game">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <strong>Big Game of Interest:</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="muledeer" type="checkbox" name="muledeer" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Mule Deer</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="whitetaildeer" type="checkbox" name="whitetaildeer" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Whitetail Deer</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="antelope" type="checkbox" name="antelope" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Antelope</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="elk" type="checkbox" name="elk" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Elk</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="mountainlion" type="checkbox" name="mountainlion" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Mountain Lion</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="mountaingoat" type="checkbox" name="mountaingoat" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Mountain Goat</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="bear" type="checkbox" name="bear" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Bear</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="bighornsheep" type="checkbox" name="bighornsheep" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Bighorn Sheep</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="moose" type="checkbox" name="moose" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Moose</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <!-- Small Game -->
      <fieldset id="small-game">
        <p><strong>Small Game of Interest:</strong>
        </p>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input value="smallgame" type="checkbox" name="smallgame" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">General Small Game</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input value="turkey" type="checkbox" name="turkey" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Turkey</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input value="uplandbirds" type="checkbox" name="uplandbirds" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Upland Birds</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input value="waterfowl" type="checkbox" name="waterfowl" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Waterfowl</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input value="varmints" type="checkbox" name="varmints" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Varmints</label>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <!-- Lodging -->
      <fieldset id="lodging">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <strong>Lodging:</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="lodge" type="checkbox" name="lodge" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Lodge</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="cabins" type="checkbox" name="cabins" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Cabins</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="trailers" type="checkbox" name="trailers" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Trailers</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="tents" type="checkbox" name="tents" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Tents</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="motel" type="checkbox" name="motel" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Motel</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="wildernesscamps" type="checkbox" name="wildernesscamps" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Wilderness Camps</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="handicapaccessible" type="checkbox" name="handicapaccessible" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Handicap Accessible</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="camping" type="checkbox" name="camping" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Camping</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="dropcamps" type="checkbox" name="dropcamps" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Drop Camps</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <!-- Summer Recreation -->
      <fieldset id="summer">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <strong>Summer Recreation:</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="flyfishing" type="checkbox" name="flyfishing" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Fly Fishing</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="spincasting" type="checkbox" name="spincasting" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Spin Casting</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="lakefishing" type="checkbox" name="lakefishing" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Lake Fishing</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="streamfishing" type="checkbox" name="streamfishing" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Stream Fishing</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="floattrips" type="checkbox" name="floattrips" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Float Trips</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="rafting" type="checkbox" name="rafting" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Rafting</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="other" type="checkbox" name="other" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Other</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <!-- Special Services -->
      <fieldset id="services">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <strong>Special Services:</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="packtrips" type="checkbox" name="packtrips" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Pack Trips</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="horserides" type="checkbox" name="horserides" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Horse Rides</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="cattledrives" type="checkbox" name="cattledrives" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Cattle Drives</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="horserental" type="checkbox" name="horserental" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Horse Rental</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="guideschools" type="checkbox" name="guideschools" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Guide Schools</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input value="overnighttrips" type="checkbox" name="overnighttrips" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Overnight Trips</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <!-- Winter -->
      <fieldset id="winter">
        <p><strong>Winter:</strong>
        </p>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input value="sleighrides" type="checkbox" name="sleighrides" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Sleigh Rides</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input value="snowmobiletours" type="checkbox" name="snowmobiletours" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">SnowMobile Tours/Rental</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input value="skiing" type="checkbox" name="skiing" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Skiing</label>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <!-- Operating Area -->
      <fieldset id="operating-area">
        <p><strong>Operating Area</strong>
        </p>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input value="blm" type="checkbox" name="blm" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">BLM</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input value="nationalforest" type="checkbox" name="nationalforest" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">National Forest</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input value="privateland" type="checkbox" name="privateland" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Private Land</label>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <!-- Other -->
      <fieldset id="other">
        <p><strong>Other</strong>
        </p>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input value="ranchingforwildlife" type="checkbox" name="ranchingforwildlife" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Ranching for Wildlife</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input value="workingcattleranch" type="checkbox" name="workingcattleranch" data-bind="checked: activeFilters">Working Cattle Ranch</label>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```